# Procedure expects a parameter which "was not supplied"

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, stored-procedures

I hate asking for help (in general) but also on here because most of my issues are probably easily solvable, but I'm new-ish to programming and cannot get past this bug.

I'm developing a C# application that takes user input from a .NET form and passes it to a database. On the click of a button, a method is called that generates and inserts a random ID into a column in the DB, stores the newly generated ID into a hidden field, and then calls the stored procedure to populate the rest of the data from what was typed in the webform fields.

Most of this was working fine until I started to store the ID in the hidden field, and now things have gone downhill. Now, I'm getting the error: "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Procedure or function 'User_Add' expects parameter '@UID', which was not supplied."

I have tried rearranging the code to position the method that generates the ID first, then calling the stored procedure, and even using a stored procedure to insert the ID into the table. Regardless of whatever rearrangements I make, I still get this error. I'm not sure what else I should be doing. Does anyone have suggestions? Below is *some* of my code; I've replaced the actual names of variables and whatnot with placeholders and eliminated several of the parameters for simplicity's sake:

```
        public void UserDataPassage(string cnxnString)
        {
            using (SqlConnection cnxn = new SqlConnection(cnxnString))
            {
                cnxn.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[Users_Add]", cnxn);

                // Create and prepare an SQL statement
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlParameter item1Param = new SqlParameter("@item1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                SqlParameter item2Param = new SqlParameter("@item2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                
                // Check to see if values are null; pass to DB as a null value if true
                try
                {
                    if (item1Param == null)
                    {
                        item1Param.Value = DBNull.Value;
                    }
                    if (item2Param == null)
                    {
                        item2Param.Value = DBNull.Value;
                    }
                }
                catch (InvalidCastException)
                {

                }

                // Equate the parameters to the ASP IDs created in Default.aspx
                item1Param.Value = box_box1name.Text;
                item2Param.Value = box_box2name.Text;                   

                // Add values to the RBuilder database.
                cmd.Parameters.Add(item1Param).ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.Add(item2Param).ToString();

                // Call Prepare after setting the commandtext parameters
                cmd.Prepare();

                // Execute the query (does not return any values);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                
            }
        }
```

And my stored procedure is as follows:

```
USE [TestDB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[User_Add]
    
    @item1 NVARCHAR(50),
    @item2 NVARCHAR(50),
    @userID INT OUT

AS

BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [Table1] (item1, item2)
    VALUES (@item1, @item2)

SET  @userID= SCOPE_IDENTITY()


END
```

Comment: *"expects parameter '@UID"* - I don't see anything in the code called `UID`.  I see a `userID` parameter which isn't supplied though...

Comment: As an aside, it's never appropriate to catch `InvalidCastException`, especially not to silently discard it, as you can always avoid producing this exception in the first place. It's what Eric Lippert would call a [bone-headed exception](https://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/).

Comment: The following may be helpful: [SqlParameter.Direction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.direction?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) and  [Configuring parameters and parameter data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types#supplying-the-parameterdirection-property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the output parameter. Your stored procedure requires 3 parameters. You need to supply the Parameter even if you won't use it.

```
SqlParameter userId = new SqlParameter("@userID", SqlDbType.Int);
OutputParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(OutputParam);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply the `@UID` parameter as an output parameter

```cs
SqlParameter uidParam = new SqlParameter("@UID", SqlDbType.Int) {Direction = ParameterDirection.Output};
cmd.Parameters.Add(uidParam);
```

The `ToString` seems superfluous, and `cmd.Prepare()` is also unnecessary.

---

Furthermore, your check for `null` makes no sense as you are checking the actual parameter object, which is never null. You can instead do this

```cs
cmd.Parameters.Add("@item1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = box_box1name.Text ?? (object) DBNull.Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@item2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = box_box2name.Text ?? (object) DBNull.Value;
```